# VueJs Understanding v-model and v-on:click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, v-model

I'm currently trying to learn VueJS coming from a jQuery background and I've run into something that I either don't understand or trying to do wrongly. I'm using VueJS and Laravel. I add VueJS to my blade templates.

I have table set up with a few rows of data. In those rows I have a text input field. Each row also contains two icons that allow me to move the row up or down.

When I click on the icon I want to send a axios request telling my database to update the order field. When it returns a success message I want to reload the table with the new order.

After clicking the v-onclick icon and reloading the table into my div with an axios get the v-onclick stops working. Also the v-model binding that I've set up also stops working. When I update a value in a text input it no longer updates the value in the data property.

I've added a jsFiddle to give an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.
I use axios to get a route that returns the products table view.

````
            ```reload : function(){
                url = '/products;
                axios.get(url).then(response => {
                    document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = response.data;
                });
            },```
````

https://jsfiddle.net/k8Lj4asb/1/

Comment: Hi, your JSFiddle is broken. Please atleast fix your JSFiddle and then you may get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to update a table in VueJS. By manipulating the DOM directly, you perform changes to the site that Vue doesn't track (and hence doesn't know about), which breaks reactivity.

The proper way to do this would be to store your list in a Vuex-Store and perform the update in there. I recommend reading up on the topic using the excellent documentation provided here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Vuex may be a little to heavy for someone whos just getting started and is trying to learn Vue from a jQuery background. Vuex isn't neccesary for his use case but you are correct that due to DOM manipulation the reactivity is being broken.

Comment: Fair point, Vuex isn't necessary to do this. That being said, as a beginner I found it actually easier to do something very similar with Vuex rather than doing it without it.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the object of products to javascript, Laravel has a package for this https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer by Jeffrey Way.

Edit: oh cancel that, it looked from your broken fiddle you were trying to do something different.

In your axios response handler just update a data property for products with the response data. Then loop that property in VUE, no PHP side loop required.

```
  <td v-for="product in products">
    <input v-model="product.id" type="text" :name="product.name">
  </td>
```

Comment: So I figured that if I'd just reload the table containing the product rows with a get after updating the rows with a new order in the db vue would see that the v-models and v-onclicks would be there again and everything would keep working.

Comment: @user960722 i'm not really following what you are trying to do with both the `fetchProducts` and `reload` methods. I think using php to build the list rather than the products data in vue may be your issue?

Comment: fetchProducts returns a json array containing the products you see in the data property. I thought that I may needed to refresh those after reloading the table through an axios get to make v-model see them again?

Comment: @user960722 in that case, just call `fetchProducts` again instead of reload and let it update the products